# I don't understand Perl's "-e" operator

Tags: perl

I see Perl scripts using `-e`, for example `unless -e`

I understand the `unless` loop, but not the `-e` part. An explanation would be nice. When should `-e` be used?

Comment: Your title implies that you're asking about the `-e` command line option, as in `perl -e 'print time, "\n"'`, but I think you're asking about the `-e` operator. You might want to update your question to make it clearer what you're asking.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, I will edit that right now.

Comment: When editing an unclear question, it's generally better to rewrite it as it should have been written in the first place rather than just adding an addendum. I've edited it for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's to check if a file exists.

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html

Answer (score 1):

That's testing if a file exists

Check [`perldoc -f -X`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html)

Comment: `perldoc -X` doesn't work. You can use `perldoc -f -X` or `perldoc -f -e`. (`perldoc -f foo` shows the documentation for the function `foo`).

Comment: @KeithThompson I wasn't actually trying to point to the command line perldoc, hence the link to perl.org.  However, that's a good idea, so edited.   Feel free to just edit yourself next time.